# What permission or access to set on appcast xml.signature files

Tags: netsparkle

I am in the process of using netsparkle for updates in my Avalonia app and I have everything working in test.
I'm just wondering about what permissions I should set on the appcast.xml.signature.
I know this file needs to be there or the signature can't be checked in the appcast.xml file.
I assume that as long as my private key isn't exposed this is OK?

Answer (score 0):

After going through the issues list on the Netsparkle GitHub repo I found an issue that answers my question;

https://github.com/NetSparkleUpdater/NetSparkle/issues/256

As I thought, key things are to

1. Protect your private key
2. Make sure no one can replace the binary and appcast on your server.